# c++ program not getting executed using php script with commands like exec(),shell_exec(),system()

Tags: php, c++, shell-exec

I am trying to compile and execute c++ program using php script in Ubuntu 12.04.The c++ program is getting compiled and even a.out is getting created but the only problem is that ./a.out is not working.
I have tried most of commands to run ./a.out like system(),exec(),shell_exec(),backtick,passthru etc.
Now for the sake of simplicity a.out is created in the same directory in which the php file resides.I am posting here the code

```
 $target = $_GET['name'];
 chmod($target,0777); 
 $handle = fopen("compile.sh", "x+");
 chmod("compile.sh",0777);
 $data = "g++ ".$target;     
 fwrite($handle, $data);
 fclose($handle);  
 system("sh compile.sh");    
 chmod("a.out", 0777);   
 system("./a.out");
```

I am getting the name of file to be compiled from the url and so on.The above code works fine upto penultimate line i.e chmod("a.out",0777) but the output of cpp program is not getting displayed.
**And the most funniest part is that same code works perfectly fine for c program**after changing g++ to gcc.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? Also don't try this at home, kids: `script.php?name=&amp;&amp;+rm+-rf+/`

Comment: @fab dats fine now i changed the code even then the last command is not working.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem which was due to file libgcc_s.so.1 giving an error

> /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 : version 'GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by
>   /usr/lib/libstdcc+.so.6)

all i did was to replace this file which lies in the lib folder of lampp directory by the libgcc_s.so in gcc directory and renaming it to libgcc_s.so.1.